# Is Apollo 18 real or just a fiction film?

Tags: apollo-18

**Is *Apollo 18* a real documentary as the introduction of the film says, or just another science fiction film?**

If it is science fiction, then why does the film say it is based on real footage found in Apollo 18?

It also gives reference to a website which redirects to another one http://lunartruth.org/

Comment: The Apollo portion of the real-world [Apollo–Soyuz Test Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo%E2%80%93Soyuz_Test_Project) has been referred to as "Apollo 18", though it was officially unnumbered.

Comment: @KeithThompson - define "pettiness" - in USSR it was officially called "Soyuz-Apollon" :)

Comment: It would be very hard to secretly launch a Saturn V...

Comment: Don't believe everything in fictional movies or on the internet

Answer (score 44):

It's a fiction - the same way that *Blair Witch Project* is a fiction (using "real found footage") and *Paranormal Activity*.

All of these films make use of multiple media to create the illusion that something really did happen - in fact, *Blair Witch Project* was probably one of the very first movies to do this.

This film quite cleverly taps into willingness of people to believe in conspiracies (although, ironically, this is a conspiracy about actually having gone to the Moon) - but it is still a fiction.

From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_18_%28film%29) on the film:

> *Apollo 18* is a 2011 American science fiction horror film written by Brian Miller, directed by Gonzalo López-Gallego, and produced by Timur Bekmambetov and Ron Schmidt. The film's premise is that the canceled Apollo 18 mission actually landed on the moon in December 1974 but never returned, and as a result the United States has never launched another expedition to the Moon. The film is shot in found-footage style, supposedly the lost footage of the Apollo 18 mission that was only recently discovered.

Comment: Cloverfield also uses this ploy - civilian VT footage found at 'Cloverfield' site. Surely we'd have heard about NY City being mauled by a giant mauling-thing in the news _before_ they made the movie. I know I miss the 9pm news occasionally, but still . . .

Comment: It should be noted that there is evidence that throughout the 1960s NASA in cooperation with the military prepared to put astronauts into orbit on spying missions. This was the era before and during which spy satellites became possible. Whether they actually did so or not we won't know for a long time, I suspect. But it's that little kernel of truth that the fiction is built around.

Comment: Timur Bekmambetov should be a dead giveaway - he was the guy who produced "Nightwatch" movies, wildly popular Russian fantasy "blockbusters" based on Lukyanenko's books.

Comment: @MarkLysaght - well, if it coninsided with Kim Kardashian's wedding, the latter may have taken the news cycle precedence.

Comment: @Dvk: Hmmm, good point.

Comment: @JohnO - Actually, I think that most, if not all of the recon satellite stuff from that era has been declassified. Look up "Keyhole satellites".

Comment: And its a irony too that the question has -4 reputation points whereas the answer has +36...

Answer (score 0):

It is a fiction film. This is quite obvious for me because I am an astrophysics student and I know a lot about moon and why it can't support life. Moon has no atmosphere and no minerals to support life. The pressure is extremely low and any fluid would sublimate. Life can not exist without fluid.

There are many more reasons why the movie is fake. The movie really fools those who have limited scientific knowledge and those people are the targeted audience.

Answer (score 0):

According to the film's Technical Advisor, Gerry Griffin, the film was wholly fictional.

> *But unlike NASA, Griffin noted "**this is all make believe**". He recalled
> his time with Ron Howard on Apollo 13 wherein Howard kept him close to
> him at all times to make sure no technical mistakes were made but
> reminded Griffin "**this is not a documentary**".*
>
> <sub><sup>[Apollo 18: A Review And Interview With Technical Advisor Gerry Griffin](http://www.spaceref.com/news/viewnews.html?id=1564)</sup></sub>

Of course, he would say that, [wouldn't he](http://www.bdcwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/x-files-truth-is-out-there-gif.gif).